# How to use a function member of an object from an array passed to a function by pointer?

Tags: c++

So here are 2 functions I am working on :

```
void Ville::sous_la_moyenne( int moyenne, Tableau<Quartier>* quartiersSousMoyenne )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < nbQuartiers_; i++ )
    {
        if( quartiers_[i].get_revenuMoyen() < moyenne )
        {
            quartiersSousMoyenne->ajouter( quartiers_[i] );
        }
    }
}

void Ville::afficher_quartier_sous_moy( Tableau<Quartier>* quartiersSousMoyenne )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < quartiersSousMoyenne->taille(); i++ )
    {
        cout << quartiersSousMoyenne[i]->get_nom() << " Revenu moyen:"
        << quartiersSousMoyenne[i]->set_revenuMoyen() << endl;
    }
}
```

**This doesn't work :** 
- `quartiersSousMoyenne[i]->get_nom()`
- `quartiersSousMoyenne[i]->set_revenuMoyen()`

**I tried :** 
- `quartiersSousMoyenne[i].get_nom()`
- `*( quartiersSousMoyenne[i] ).get_nom()`
- `*quartiersSousMoyenne[i].get_nom()`
- `*(quartiersSousMoyenne + i).get_nom()`

**It says:** "No member named 'set_revenuMoyen' in 'Tableau'"

If you see in the first function, named *sous_la_moyenne*, there is an instance of *Tableau* named *quartiers_*. I access its element with *[i]* and I then use the function *get_revenuMoyen()* which is a function of the class *Quartier*.

I would like now to do the same thing but for a pointer of *Tableau*... if that's even possible.

I successfully make it work w/o pointer, but I don't want to make a copy of an object.

P.S. Don't try to understand the meaning of the variables names... I speak french :D. **Tableau** means array though - This one's important.

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in the [help] for creating a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste, attempt to compile, and reproduce your compilation error. Otherwise, at most anyone can do is make a random guess.

Comment: Note that `quartiersSousMoyenne[i]` will dereference the memory at `quartiersSousMoyenne + (sizeof(Tableau<Quartier>)*i)`, which is likely NOT the same location as `(*quartiersSousMoyenne)[i]` (assuming that `Tableau` is a data structure that provides an overloaded `operator[]`).  In other words, you are treating `quartiersSousMoyenne` like a raw array of `Tableau`s, but I assume you actually want to access elements *contained* by a *single* `Tableau` (but hard to say without seeing the definition of `Tableau`).

Comment: *Tableau* is a class like this *template <class T> class Tableau*. 

It's a data structure. Basically an array where I set some functions like ''add'' and ''remove'' to define the behavior.

It indeed has an overload operator [].

Comment: It is a better practice to pass structs, containers etc by reference using '&' in place of raw pointer '*'

Comment: Thx TheArquitect - works ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually TheArquitect gave me a good advice. He said it's better to use & (reference), instead of * (pointer) to pass an object.

It works like this :

```
void Ville::afficher_quartier_sous_moy( Tableau<Quartier>& quartiersSousMoyenne )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < quartiersSousMoyenne.taille(); i++ )
    {
        cout << quartiersSousMoyenne[i].get_nom() << " Revenu moyen:"
        << quartiersSousMoyenne[i].get_revenuMoyen() << endl;
    }
}
```

I consider the case solved.